# Expressing a product of spherical harmonics as Wigner D-matrices

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

The standard addition of angular momentum in terms spherical harmonics $Y^{l}_m(\theta,\phi)$ is the problem of expressing the product $Y^l_m(\theta,\phi)Y^{l'}_{m'}(\theta,\phi)$ as a linear combination of single spherical harmonics. This problem has been completely solved in terms of Clebsch-Gordon coefficients and is well known among anybody who took an introductory class covering representation theory.

I am curious of a slightly different problem for which I haven't seen a treatment of. Instead, consider the product $Y^l_m(\beta,\alpha)Y^{l'}_{m'}(\beta,\gamma)$ and determine how this can be written as a linear combination of Wigner D-matrices $D^j_{mm'}(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)^*$. I will write a tentative ansatz

$$Y^l_m(\beta,\alpha)Y^{l'}_{m'}(\beta,\gamma)=\sum_jC_{j,l,l'}D^j_{mm'}(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)^*$$

It's clear that the Wigner D-matrices $m$ and $m'$ values are the same as on the LHS, but the rest of the structure is unclear to me. In trying to solve this problem algebraically, I ran into difficulties. On the LHS, we should consider two different angular momentum operators $L^{(1)}$ and $L^{(2)}$ which read

$$L^{(1)}_{\pm}=e^{\pm i\alpha}\Big(\pm \frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}+i\cot\beta\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}\Big),\quad L^{(1)}_3=-i\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}$$
$$L^{(2)}_{\pm}=e^{\pm i\gamma}\Big(\pm \frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}+i\cot\beta\frac{\partial}{\partial\gamma}\Big),\quad L^{(2)}_3=-i\frac{\partial}{\partial\gamma}$$

These are the individual angular momentum operators for each spherical harmonic if we ignore for the moment that they don't share an argument $\beta$. On the RHS, the relevant operators which characterize the D-matrices are

$$J_{\pm}=e^{\pm i\alpha}\Big(\pm\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}+i\cot\beta\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}-i\csc\beta\frac{\partial}{\partial\gamma}\Big),\quad J_3=-i\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}$$
$$P_{\pm}=e^{\pm i\gamma}\Big(\mp\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}-i\cot\beta\frac{\partial}{\partial\gamma}+i\csc\beta\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}\Big),\quad P_3=-i\frac{\partial}{\partial\gamma}$$

I started off by trying to write $L^{(1)}$ and $L^{(2)}$ in terms of $J$ and $P$, but can't figure out the right relation.

So what are the coefficients $C_{j,l,l'}$?

Comment: For those who bookmarked this question, do you have any ideas on how to solve this problem? There is a simple integral expression for these coefficients, but it does not seem to have a nice closed expression in terms of 3j symbols.